# Asp.Net MVC Checkbox+Textbox combination -> Post

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, forms

Technologies : Asp.Net MVC3 / Razor

I am generating a dynamic form with a list of questions of types listed bellow :

- Text : Question with a textbox
- Multiplechoice : Question with a list of checkboxes
- Singlechoice : Question with a list of radiobuttons

All this works perfectly, when I post the form I use a modelbinder to match the model and the selected answers

**BUT :**

Now I want to customize the Multiple and Single choice :

- Multiplechoice : Question with a list of checkboxes with or without
  an additional ***Textbox associated to a checkbox***
- Singlechoice : Question with a list of radiobuttons with or without
  an additional ***Textbox associated to a radiobutton***

When I get the posted collection in my modelbinder, I dont find a way to associate a checkbox/radio and the corresponding Textbox answer

How can I handle this ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to achieve letting the user select "Other" and fill in their own value if none of the options match.

You can do this with javascript, add your radiobutton with value Other or whatever, then assign an onBlur handler to your textbox that sets the value of your Other radiobutton to the value of the textbox. See this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/rrVps/1/